# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mephisto.core'

Tags: python, parlai

I'm using the latest version of Mephisto on macOS Catalina. I am trying to run ParlAI, and specifically the `acute_eval` task.
According to the Instructions of both [Mephisto](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Mephisto) and [AcuteEVAL](https://github.com/facebookresearch/ParlAI/tree/master/parlai/crowdsourcing/tasks/acute_eval), I should be able to execute `run.py` and get the task running. However, I get this error as I run it, using this command:

```
python run.py --pairings_filepath=example/pairings.jsonl
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "run.py", line 17, in <module>
    from parlai.crowdsourcing.tasks.acute_eval.acute_eval_blueprint import BLUEPRINT_TYPE
File "/Users/moli/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/parlai/crowdsourcing/tasks/acute_eval/acute_eval_blueprint.py", line 12, in <module>
    from mephisto.core.registry import register_mephisto_abstraction
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mephisto.core'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ParlAI installation instructions on [github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/ParlAI#installing-parlai) state that Python 3.7 or higher is required, however it appears that you are using Python 3.6. This is likely the cause of the issue, and the program should work if you upgrade your Python version.